# Caption of algorithm2e

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

I use the package `algorithm2e` for showing algorithms in my work. I want to get the caption text italic and in small. I don't know how to get it. The documentation of this package could not help me:

MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% Praeambel
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp, eurosym}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ngerman,boxed]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \caption{Caption}
\tcc{Zun"achst werden die Worte $W_i$ expandiert}
\For{i = 16 to 79}{
    $W_i \coloneqq W_{i-3} \oplus W{i-8} \oplus W_{i-14} \oplus W_{t-16}$;
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I want to get:

[image]

It would be fine if someone could help me!

Answer (score 2):

got it

```
\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\normalfont\scshape\small\itshape}
\renewcommand\AlCapNameFnt{\small\itshape}
```

Comment: Welcome. You seem to have more than one account. You should try and get these merged to enable you to interact with the site properly (e.g. properly gain rep, accept answers, comment on your own posts and so on and so forth)

Comment: The use of `\scshape` in `\AlCapFnt` is superfluous.